# Hide div if parent div's width is lower than a certain value

Tags: html, css

How to hide a div (or elements corresponding to a certain class) if container div's width is under a certain value?

Context is dynamic as the parent div is resizable thru jQuery UI resizable(). Children div should be hidden if necessary while the parent div is being resized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no css `parent` selector in the current standard of CSS, CSS3. For this, you are working with behavior, so it would be best to use JavaScript or jQuery.

Let's take an example. Suppose you have two divs

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">This is a child</div>
</div>
```

Your JavaScript file would look like this

```
var child = document.getElementById("child");
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");

parent.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    if (parent.width < 500) {
        child.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        child.style.display = "block";
   }
});
```

In jQuery, this can be accomplished like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#parent").on("resize", function() {
        $("this").width() < 500 ? $("#child").hide() : $("#child").show();
    });
});
```

Note that the jQuery `width()` method doesn't include padding, border or margin.

In both of these cases, we are listening for the `resize` event, which occurs when an element's size changes. Every time it does, it runs a check to determine whether the parent's width is less than a certain threshold. If it is, the child element will be hidden. Otherwise, it will be shown.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to mention that this behavior should happen in a dynamic context: the parent div can be resized with jQuery UI resizable. So, while the parent div's width is being changed while dragging one of its west/east border, contained div should disappear if the width goes under a certain value.

Comment: Understood, now it should work for that

Comment: Thanks Richard, it's working! But I'm wondering: is there a pure CSS way to do it?

Comment: Like I said, there isn't. There's no css selector for working with a parent selector. I don't even think it's possible with a pre-processor such as SASS

Comment: @Fred - a media query perhaps?

Comment: I mean element queries (eq.js and similar...) ... but thats not pure CSS again.

Comment: This answer is quite old. Is it currently possibile to achieve the same result using CSS only? I'm thinking about "container queries" or pseudo-elements like ":has" or ":where"... Just an idea.